# How to parse out text from a span using curl in bash?

Tags: html, bash, curl

I am using Geektools (bash desktop widget app for mac) to try and display text from a website. I have been trying to cURl the site and then grep the text but I am finding it more difficult than I imagined. Just looking for some help.

HTML:

```
     <div is>
    <div class="page-status status-none">
      <span class="status font-large">
        All Systems Operational
      </span>
      <span class="last-updated-stamp  font-small"></span>
    </div>
```

Above is the span that is displayed when I cURL the site. I just need to display the text "All Systems Operational".

Thank in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Sorry, should have added my latest attempt. I have tired several options but the closest was getting it to display the class.

Comment: curl -s "website url" | grep "status font-large" | sed 's/<div class=\"status font-large\" | sed 's/<\/div>/\n/'

Comment: Use an XML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint, ...).

Comment: @rubberfishstudios, did any of the responses work for you?

Answer (score 1):

getting in the habit of using regular expressions with html is a slippery slope; it's not the right tool for the job, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3276552); I'd suggest either

- [`hxselect`](http://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/man1/hxselect.html) from the html-xml-utils package
- [`xidel`](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html)

both of which let you use css3 selectors to target content in your input

for example:

```
curl -s $website_url | hxselect '.status.font-large' 
All Systems Operational
```

Comment: `brew install html-xml-utils` is an easy way to install hxselect.

Comment: Any Windows powershell equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe the output of curl into gawk. This gawk command seems to do the trick (I'm using Cygwin's gawk on Windows):

gawk "/status font-large/ {wantedLine=NR+1} {if (NR==wantedLine) {print $0}}"

Comment: And if you want leading/trailing spaces removed from the displayed line you can add $1=$1; before the if:

"/status font-large/ {wantedLine = NR + 1} {$1=$1; if (NR == wantedLine) {print $0}}"

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think gawk will get me what I need. However, when I use it, it doesn't return anything. Not even an error. If I change it to awk it will display a 0.

Comment: I see that wantedLine is a variable but I don't see how it is being defined. Do I need to define /status font-large/ as the variable?

Comment: Yes, wantedLine is a variable. In awk there's no need to define/declare variables. If referenced before they exist, they return the value 0 or the empty string depending on their usage. Perhaps on a Mac you need to use ' instead of " around the program text? I'd try that first. Do any of those other characters have special meaning to a Mac command line?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but the code appear to break down as such; status font-large = NR+1, which means that the row number that status font-large is found on is equal to the NR or entire text plus 1 line. If NR == status font-large, which it wont because it is on line 359 of 1400 lines, then print.

Comment: Using this "Control Statements in AWK" as a reference on this site https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/Howawk-ward/Howawk-ward.html. I have created this code: 
 
        curl $website_url | awk {if ($0 ~ /status font-large/) {print $0;} else {print "NOMATCH: ";}}

I have tried with and without quotes. It produces this error -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: NR always represents the current record (line) number. As awk processes this script, for each line it: (1) searches for "status font-large". When it finds a line which contains that, it sets wantedLine to NR + 1. (2) It checks to see if the the current line (NR) is equal to wantedLine. If it is, it prints the current line.

Comment: Try a test. Does the following print all lines from the file from the site? curl $website_url | awk '{print $0}'

Comment: Thank you for your continued support BillS. When I tried the test it repeated a 0 on every line. Since I know that the text is on line 593 I placed $593 in there and it repeated 93 on every line.

Comment: Let's try putting the script into a file instead of specifying it on the command line. Put "{print $0}" -- excluding the quotes -- into a file. Let's call it test.awk. Then the awk portion of the command line would be "awk -f test.awk" (again, exclude the quotes). Does it still print many lines containing nothing but 0?

Comment: In the test, it produced the error `0curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1448)`. It didn't produce anything in the bash widget. Also I noticed that the repeating zeros, it also has a block of text half way down:
-0
-0
100 -0
56836  1-0
00 5-0
6836-0
    0     -0
0  -0
 4-0
03-0
k-0
  -0
  -0
  -0
0 --:---0
:-- --:-0
--:-0
-- --:-0
--:---0
  408-0
k
-0
-0
-0

Comment: Ok, I got the test to work `curl $Website_URL | awk "{print $0}"` it was slanting my quotations and I needed them to be straight. However, it is still repeating a 0 on each line.

Comment: Something is wrong/broken. Not supposed to work that way. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to parse out the status that I was looking for by using Nokogiri.

```
curl -s $Website_URL | nokogiri -e 'puts $_.at_css("span.status").text'
```

Comment: Any Windows powershell equivalent?